# (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out

Tags: python, django, django-models

ERRORS:
blog.Post.author: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

I know that I need to swap in settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL for auth.User, but for some reason doing this causes my blog to not show up. The routing is correct when I try to view blog from navigation bar but there is no content anymore. I also cannot login or create a new user on Django admin. These issues started occuring with setting an AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings for accounts.

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from fitness_project import settings


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='User')
    #author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello',
    'blog',
    'membership',
    'accounts',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.backends.EmailAuth',
)
```

blog/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

Answer (score 12):

Since you have set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'`, your model should be:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

However, it is extremely difficult to [switch to a custom user model for an existing project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). If you are trying to do this, you may find it easiest to drop your database, delete your migrations, then re-run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562402/fields-e301-field-defines-a-relation-with-the-model-auth-user-which-has-bee) is correct, but here's my little more modification to it.

As you have already imported - `from fitness_project import settings` , You can also assign a var named User, so you can use it next time in your model's fields

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

And then, as usual you can use User like this -

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='User')
```